# Using cmudict to count syllables

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that uses CMU Pronouncing Dictionary (cmudict.txt) to count all the syllables from a text file that contains English words. What would be the best approach? 
The program is supposed to analyze some provided text files by counting number of words, sentences, and characters. I was able to finish these parts without any problem. Now, I'm trying to figure out how I can use the cmudict.txt provided to count the number of syllables. I'm not sure where to start.
Thanks!

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("")) {
            numParagraph++;
        }
        if (!(line.equals(""))) {
            // Count number of Characters in file
            numChar += line.length();
            // Count number of words in file
            String[] wordList = line.split("\\s+");
            numWords += wordList.length;
            // Count number of sentences in a file
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if(delimiters.indexOf(line.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                    sentenceCount++;
                }
            }
            //Average number of Characters per word
            wordListLength = wordList.length;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use CMUdict to count syllables, you simply need to find a CMUdict entry that corresponds to the word you're analyzing. Once you have an entry, you can count the vowel sounds in it. The vowel sounds always end in a numeric digit, either 0, 1, or 2.

There is a module called cmudict which automatically imports the CMUdict library and preprocesses it. You should start there.

```
import cmudict

def lookup_word(word_s):
    return cmudict.dict().get(word_s)

def count_syllables(word_s):
    count = 0
    phones = lookup_word(word_s) # this returns a list of matching phonetic rep's
    if phones:                   # if the list isn't empty (the word was found)
        phones0 = phones[0]      #     process the first
        count = len([p for p in phones0 if p[-1].isdigit()]) # count the vowels
    return count

word_s = 'hello'
phones = cmudict.dict().get(word_s)
count = count_syllables(word_s)
print(f"PHONES({word_s!r}) yields {phones}\nCOUNT is {count}")
```

You can do a lot more with CMUdict than the above, but it's a start...

PS - Rereading your post, I see I missed part of it.
You can use a regular expression (regex) to split all the input text by white space and punctuation marks. That should give you all the words. Then you can run each word, one at a time, through the above routine to calculate the number of syllables for the word, and sum the syllable counts as you go along.
You can also use the above to verify your previous word count. But your current routine for counting words probably only detects the beginning of each word, not the end, and may not help you with this unless you extend it to detect the end of the word, as well. If you do that, you can disregard the regex for splitting.

Comment: Note that some words can have varying syllable counts.  A great example is the word "resume," as in the sentence, "Please resume writing your resume." The first appearance has two syllables and the second has three syllables.  So, the above code could be rewritten to check all phonetic representations and return a single value if all are the same, or return a (smallest, biggest) tuple otherwise.

Comment: Although your code is in Java, I hope you can understand the syntax of Python well enough to extract the logic...